# Pass object using JSON

Tags: javascript, json

right now i am using Json for passing status and message like

```
return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "Save successfully" });

 Project model=new Project()
```

Is there any way, i can send model in json also?
I am using c# and asp.net mvc

Comment: what is `Json`? I'm guessing its a serializer, but if so, it should have a lowercase 'j' as it is not a class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it is very easy. The `Json` method accepts any object:

```
return Json(new Project());
```

Comment: how can i pass this object in
return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "Save successfully" });, i had tried this like 
return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "Save successfully", Object = model }); but it is not accessible on my view

Comment: It should be. You can check with FireBug or Fiddler what is being sent over the wire. Generally speaking you should be able to serialize most of things (objects) as JSON.

Comment: yes you are right i am getting this on view. i am getting data.CheckListItem, but in form of object. i want to do like this.

 data = eval('(' + data + ')');
 $("#remote-tab-1").html(data.CheckListItem);

Comment: when i am doing data = eval('(' + data + ')');  it return data object, my object inside this data object. how can i access this.